# What is the function represented by the power series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k(x-1)^k}{3^k}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions, power-series

Find the function represented by the power series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k(x-1)^k}{3^k}.$$

---

I know that the interval of convergence for the power series is $(-2, 4)$, would that help much?  I also know that the power series can be written as $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k y^k,$$ where $y=\frac{x-1}{3}$.  Would that help?

Answer (score 3):

This is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty ky^k$ with $y=(x-1)/3$. Then
$$\frac d{dy}\sum_{k=0}^\infty y^k$$ is
something a bit like $\sum_{k=1}^\infty ky^k$ surely?

Comment: How would this help?